# How to add Facebook friends profile pictures to a HTML5 Canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am pretty new to HTML5 and was wondering how I would go about adding 10 random Facebook friends profile image's using JavaScript to an HTML5 Canvas, I have searched all over the net and have yet to find a solution that works, below is an example that I have been playing about with, I have created a Facebook App with the required permissions and can get a list of friends and their profile images I just can not figure out how to add them to the HTML5 Canvas.

```
<script>
  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }

  window.onload = function(images) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var sources = {
      canvasbackground: "prof.jpg",
      userpic1: "https://graph.facebook.com/1645410740/picture",
      userpic2: "https://graph.facebook.com/100000557085310/picture"
    };

        loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.canvasbackground, 0, 0, 422, 464);
        context.drawImage(images.userpic1, 33, 28, 70, 70);
        context.drawImage(images.userpic2, 130, 28, 70, 70);
    });
  };

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `drawImage` expects an `Image` object, not a url.

Comment: Hi Shmiddty as far as I can tell the image object is created using "for(var src in sources) { images[src] = new Image();" near the beginning of the code and the URL of the image's is then passed to that object, I can get the images to load using the URL no problem it is now just a matter of adding 10 random Facebook friends image's using JavaScript to the HTML5 Canvas. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're right, the code looks sound. Is your `loadImages` callback being called?

Comment: I'm going to assume that it is something to do with your image links never being loaded. Try it with another image that isn't `https`

Answer (score 0):

so, yea first of all i would change the numImages to just equal sources.length,  then for the callback, do

```
if( ! -- numImages ){ // once it gets down to 0, it's done, probably want to name it loadingImages
   //done 
}
```

put some console logs in and see what's actually happening.